# Can anybody explain me how celery group worked?

Tags: python, celery

When I use celery group and chains to schedule the tasks as below

```
(group([group_task]) | sum_task).apply_async()
```

the group tasks can be executed in many workers, after all group tasks finished, sum_task begin to execute(maybe in the other worker), so 
who can tell me how celery known the group tasks are all finished and then started the sum_task?

Answer (score 1):

You could specify queue for each chained task and group/chord callback task differently.

Snippet like:

```
@shared_task(name="analyze_atom", queue="atom")
def analyze_atom(image_urls, targetdir=target_path, studentuid=None):
    return {}


@shared_task(name="summary_up", queue="summary")
def summary_up(rets, studentuid, images):
    return {}


chord(analyze_atom.s([image]) for image in images)(summary_up.s(studentuid, images))
```

And, when tasks running, you could inspect broker content, assume you are using rabbitmq as broker, you could inspect queue depth by rabbitmq management plugin, or pyrabbit interface snippet here:

```
from pyrabbit.api import Client
cl = Client('localhost:15672', 'guest', 'guest')
count = cl.get_queue_depth('/', 'summary')   # this guy check queue depth
cl.get_messages('/','paperanalyzer')  # this guy get messages within queue
```

And, you should have result backend, you could get every task result by task id.

I think upon skills above, it's easy to inspect how celery task goes on.

Good luck :-)